# Socket not working over https

Tags: node.js, http, https, socket.io

Unable to make a connection between server and client using sockets. Getting following error.

```
GET https://**.**.**.**:9000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LvBYNwb net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
Request.create @ socket.io.js:1456
Request @ socket.io.js:1369
XHR.request @ socket.io.js:1297
XHR.doPoll @ socket.io.js:1327
Polling.poll @ socket.io.js:1740
Polling.doOpen @ socket.io.js:1684
Transport.open @ socket.io.js:827
Socket.open @ socket.io.js:248
Socket @ socket.io.js:129
Socket @ socket.io.js:55
Manager.open.Manager.connect @ socket.io.js:4549
(anonymous) @ socket.io.js:4859
setTimeout (async)
Manager.reconnect @ socket.io.js:4849
(anonymous) @ socket.io.js:4863
(anonymous) @ socket.io.js:4570
Emitter.emit @ socket.io.js:2556
Socket.onError @ socket.io.js:688
(anonymous) @ socket.io.js:279
Emitter.emit @ socket.io.js:2556
Transport.onError @ socket.io.js:814
(anonymous) @ socket.io.js:1333
Emitter.emit @ socket.io.js:2556
Request.onError @ socket.io.js:1502
(anonymous) @ socket.io.js:1449
setTimeout (async)
xhr.onreadystatechange @ socket.io.js:1448
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
Request.create @ socket.io.js:1456
Request @ socket.io.js:1369
XHR.request @ socket.io.js:1297
XHR.doPoll @ socket.io.js:1327
Polling.poll @ socket.io.js:1740
Polling.doOpen @ socket.io.js:1684
Transport.open @ socket.io.js:827
Socket.open @ socket.io.js:248
Socket @ socket.io.js:129
Socket @ socket.io.js:55
Manager.open.Manager.connect @ socket.io.js:4549
(anonymous) @ socket.io.js:4859
```

Server(node.js) and client both are over HTTPS. If Client is over HTTP, sockets are working fine but as soon as it is changed to HTTPS result is the error.
Unable to config the sockets to work with HTTPS.

Server Side:

```
import express from 'express';
import http from 'http';
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var socketio = require('socket.io').listen(server, { log: true });
```

Client Side:

```
var socket = io('localhost:9000');
```

Here you go:

```
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'X-Requested-With,Accept,Content-Type, Origin';
proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,DELETE, POST,PUT, OPTIONS';
add_header 'Content-Type' 'application/json';
```

Nginx HTTPS config:

```
listen 443 ssl default_server;
if ($ssl_protocol = "") {
rewrite ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}
ssl_certificate /etc/example.com/ssl-bundle.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/example.com/example.key;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
```

This is the error now i am getting on example.com:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://example.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LvC2GP8. The
>   value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response
>   is 'true, true' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials
>   mode is 'include'. Origin 'https://staging.zikher.com' is therefore
>   not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the
>   XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Comment: Your server side doesn't use HTTPS.

Comment: I have setup nginx for HTTPS. I did setup HTTPS on my server side but wasn't able to make it work due to nginx, need some guidance for this.

Comment: Can you add the relevant portion of your NGINX configuration (the proxy-part) to your question?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add it there? You're posting it as a comment now.

Comment: Sorry for that, did that

Comment: Nowhere is Nginx configured to listen for HTTPS.... check your config.

Comment: @Brad, this is the HTTPS config for nginx

Comment: You have two different places in your server code that are setting the value of the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` response header to `true`. You need to remove one of them.

Comment: yeah I figured that out, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that NGINX is running on port 443, your client is connecting to the wrong port (9000, which is what the Express server is listening on, but the client should connect to the NGINX proxy).

Try this in the client:

```
var socket = io();
```

Or, to connect over HTTPS to a specific server (and HTTPS port, 443):

```
var socket = io('https://server.example.com')
```

Comment: Client and Server side are running on different servers. So i defined a IP with port for the server side.

Comment: @Shanky okay, so use `var socket = io('https://your.server/')` (without a port number)

Comment: ``XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://example.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LvC2GP8. The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is 'true, true' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'https://example1.com' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.``